# How can I access a sub-object in JsonDataObjects

Tags: json, delphi

Say I have the following JSON object, how can I access, directly (without iterating over the entire array of items), a subarray item of it, using Delphi and JsonDataObjects

```json
{"menu": {
    "header": "SVG Viewer",
    "items": [
        {"id": "Open"},
        {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
        null,
        {"id": "Help"},
        {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
    ]
}}
```

What is the Delphi code to directly access the subarray with `id = "About"` and read the label property?

Comment: You need to iterate. Clearly something has to iterate. And it's you!

Comment: I made [jsonDoc](https://github.com/stijnsanders/jsonDoc#jsonDoc) for myself so I could do this by accessing an array of OleVariants

Comment: For example (if I understand it correctly), library SuperObject can access that using - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   json.S['menu.items[4].id']